# digitalocean server cpu is 75% all the time

Tags: linux, memory, central-processing-unit, top

I have a nice server in digital ocean, it's the 1GB ram size.

It has installed: php, mysql, nginx, supervisored, beanstalkd as I installed.

But the problem is the I see that all the time the cpu is on 75% usage

and I look at the processes, and nothing looks like over using.

any ideas why? (attached screenshot of top command)

[image]

Comment: One for server fault I'm afraid. You might want to flag this for moving.

Comment: you suggest moving this to server fault?

Comment: Yes. 2 people have done so now.

Comment: The process with the most time spent is `supervisord` with 666 hours of processing time. Googling "supervisord high CPU use", it looks like this can happen when you have supervisord handling lots of logs - logging turned up somewhere. Can you try `ps flax` and post the output, or look at supervisord child processes? Maybe try `iotop` as well, maybe post your supervisord configuration.